# Make Ellipse by using DirectX 11

Tags: game-engine, directx-11, ellipse

```
if(shapeType == ELLIPSE)
    {
        Vertex* v = new Vertex[31];
        v[0] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
        float theta;

        for(int i = 1; i < 30; ++i)
        {
            theta = (MATH::TWO_PI * i) / static_cast<float>(30);
            v[i] = { cos(theta * i), sin(theta * i), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
        }


        HRESULT hr = this->vertexBuffer.Initialize(this->device, v,31);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            ErrorLogger::Log(hr, "Failed to create vertex buffer.");
            return false;
        }

        DWORD* indices = new DWORD[90];

        int indiceHelperNum1 = 1;
        int indiceHelperNum2 = 2;

        for(int i = 0; i < 87; i += 3)
        {
            indices[i] = 0;
            indices[i + 1] = indiceHelperNum1;
            indices[i + 2] = indiceHelperNum2;

            indiceHelperNum1++;
            indiceHelperNum2++;
        }

        indices[84] = 0;
        indices[85] = 29;
        indices[86] = 1;

        hr = this->indexBuffer.Initialize(this->device, indices, 90);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            ErrorLogger::Log(hr, "Failed to create indices buffer.");
            return false;
        }

        delete[] v;
        delete[] indices;
    }
```

This is my code and I think nothing is wrong in here except memory allocation. However, when I try this code, it doesn't work. I want to make a circle with radius one whose center is origin. I picked points by using vertex and I made triangles by using indices. Please tell me if something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with this code.

The primary problem is in the following line

```
v[i] = { cos(theta * i), sin(theta * i), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

There is no reason to multiply **theta** by **i**.

Once you resolve that issue, you should see something like this.
[image]

Notice the problem area outlined on the right side of the image.

In order to close the gap, the last 3 indices need to be modified.
Replace

```
indices[84] = 0;
indices[85] = 29;
indices[86] = 1;
```

with

```
indices[87] = 0;
indices[88] = 30;
indices[89] = 1;
```

One last thing, is your for loop to populate the vertices is not populating the last vertex at index 30. Adjust the for loops range like so

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; ++i)
{
    theta = (MATH::TWO_PI * i) / static_cast<float>(30);
    v[i] = { cos(theta ), sin(theta ), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
}
```

Finally, you should see something like this.
[image]